# How to combine head and body materials?

Tags: materials, uv

I have created a character using - head-face from AvatarSDK
body from 3rd party, and I joined both objects.
Now the problem is how to merge the head material and body material?

My scenario:

1. I created a character by join different head and body- 2 materials (head and body).
2. Exported the .obj .mtl and compressed into .zip
3. And Uploaded to mixamo for animation. after rigging I put the animated body into blender where the material is interfered like body material is combined with head.

That's the real issue.

I tried to separate head and body and applied material. It's getting but some part of colour appear in other part.

How to solve?

Comment: please add more details to your two sentence question. What do you want to achieve? maybe a screenshot or a sketch would help. How do you want to merge the materials? How does your result look like now?

Comment: @Chris sorry, first time.. ok . i updated more detailes

Comment: thanks, i think now you will get help. unfortunately this is beyond my knowledge these export/import things